# Closed terminal during upgrade after it asked something – how to get back?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 16.04, upgrade, package-management

I started upgrading to 16.04 in a terminal and was asked what to do about a change in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` vs. `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.dpkg-new`.

`D` was an option to see what the difference is between the two. I selected that and got this info:

```
--- /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades 2012-09-12 12:33:15.882829838 +0200
+++ /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.dpkg-new 2012-08-08 16:39:07.000000000 +0200 @@ -14,4 +14,4 @@
# used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
# release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
# determine if a newer release is available.
-prompt=normal
+Prompt=normal ~ (END)
```

The problem is I closed terminal because I did not know that I could use <kbd>q</kbd> to go back to the question. What can I do now to get the question back?

Answer (score 0):

The only option that ever gets set in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` is what Ubuntu releases you want to be prompted for: all releases, just LTS releases, or no prompting. So even if you don't have the chance to examine the changes, nothing would really be broken. And you can always edit the file yourself to set it how you like. Most of the file consists of comments explaining how to do this. [Here's its current contents](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/ubuntu-release-upgrader/trusty-updates/view/head:/data/release-upgrades) (see below for details):

```
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
Prompt=lts
```

So you're unlikely to have to worry about this. With that said, I've detailed several options below. I emphasize, however, that you can probably simply ignore this altogether and proceed with your upgrade.

---

If you interrupted the installation, then nothing should've been done, and running it again in the same way will usually prompt you about the same things, including newer versions of [conffiles](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#conffiles).

So I recommend doing that, unless you have a specific reason not to or you've tried it and it didn't work. I'm guessing you ran `sudo do-release-upgrade`. That should be safe to run again.

However, you could also run

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
```

since that's the package that [provides that particular file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=release-upgrades&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any). (*Don't* use the `--purge` flag, since that would typically delete the current conffile.) Then proceed to run `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

If the old file has been kept -- or has already been replaced with the new file -- *but the upgrade succeeds*, then you shouldn't have anything to worry about.

You can also [examine the new file yourself](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/ubuntu-release-upgrader/trusty-updates/view/head:/data/release-upgrades) and compare it to the one you currently have. That's the file for the 14.04 version, since you're currently running 14.04, and this is a package that gets installed *before* the upgrade to 16.04 is carried out.