# Accidentaly closed terminal during upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I was upgrading Ubuntu and when asked for something I accidentally closed the terminal.
The question was:

```
Replace the customized configuration file '/etc/sysctl.conf'?
```

Then, following the solution of [this similar topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869226/closed-terminal-during-upgrade-after-it-asked-something-how-to-get-back), I tried to make the process restart but when I give

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

it says

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
You have not rebooted after updating a package which requires a reboot. Please reboot before upgrading.
```

...What should I do to check if the upgrade is still running and/or make it continue?

---

UPDATE:
Impatiently, I tried rebooting, and now the upgrade seems to be done (from Ubuntu Mate 16.04 to 18.04), but:

- still with "sudo do-release-upgrade" it gives the same answer
- system doesn't reboot or shutdown anymore (and even the previous reboot didn't seem to be a "real" reboot... I don't know how to better explain it, it was too quick and didn't show the usual boot loader [I have Windows in another partition])
- if I open the Software Updater, it's stuck on "waiting for dpkg to exit"

...So it seems that somehow it upgraded, but something is still running or stuck.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade again to 20.04?  Or are you able to re-install the 18.04 (or another release) from scratch (without overwriting your `/home` directory)?  Honestly, either option is probably easier, unless someone else offers a better suggestion (I can't think of one).

Comment: I think running `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` may help. It also may show errors and recommend `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and/or `sudo apt install -f`in whi9ch case proceed as suggested. That said. release upgrading to 18.04 in 2022 is dumb AF. 18.04 has just a few month of support left. A proper CLEAN installation of the current release is preferable. I disagree with the previous comment by @Ray , **keeping the old /home from 16.04 is strongly discouraged**, you should backup personal files and install from scratch. And it takes much less time and effort than correcting the mess.